# Parsing Of JSON Response In JS/ JQuery

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I want to parse this `{"success":"true","data":[{"id":"15","clubid":"20","priority":"1"}]`
and i want to parse it so i can get values
Help me in this

Comment: ... and the problem is what? `JSON.parse()` will be your friend!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+parse+json

Comment: thanks to @all
solved by using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON isn't valid, anyway if it is only a typo(which is possible), [`JSON.parse(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is the function you're looking for!

Comment: now is it valid or not?

Comment: It is missing a `}` at the end

Comment: @BluAngel: You can find out here: http://jsonlint.org/.

Answer (score 1):

You won't even need to force a Parse if your JSON is valid.

If you have an object assigned to this data, for example:

```
var data = {}
```

You could most probably already access your data by referencing:

```
data.success
```

Comment: If it is a response then it will be a string, then you have to parse it. Or am I wrong?

Comment: JSON is a textual data-exchange format. If you receive it via Ajax (for example), you have to parse it.

Comment: how i can get id or clubid?

Comment: @BluAngel: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196). I also recommend to read a JavaScript tutorial, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects.

Comment: @LightStyle yes u right it is response

Comment: @BluAngel exactly what Felix Kling referenced you to. You should consider reading up on some basic Javascript, especially objects within Javascript.

In your case; try data.id and data.clubid.